# Не получаю сообщение обратно SpringBoot Okhttp

Tags: java, spring, websocket, boot, okhttp

При попытке подключиться к вебсокету, соединение устанавливается, но ответ не приходит обратно

```
    @MessageMapping("/message")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public Message greetings(Message message) {
        return messageRepo.save(message);
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
 
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/messages").setAllowedOrigins("");
    }
 
 
 
}
```

```
 public void connect() throws InterruptedException {
 
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("wss://myserver-ioan.herokuapp.com/messages")
           // .header("Content-Type","application/json")
            .build();
 
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.newWebSocket(request, new EchoWebSocketListener(client));
 
    client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }
```

```
class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
    private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
    private JsonAdapter<Message> adapter;
    private OkHttpClient client;
 
    EchoWebSocketListener(OkHttpClient client)
    {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        adapter = moshi.adapter(Message.class);
 
        this.client = client;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
      //  super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
        System.out.println("open");
       // client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
 
        Message message = new Message(5L,"Ivan","Hello");
 
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<Message> adapter = moshi.adapter(Message.class);
 
        webSocket.send(adapter.toJson(message));
        System.out.println(adapter.toJson(message));
    }
 
 
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            System.out.println("onMessage " + text);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
        System.out.println("on Close ");
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
        System.out.println("on Failure " + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

model Message

```
@Entity
public class Message {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String name;
    private String text;
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        return moshi.adapter(Message.class).toJson(this);
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
 
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
 
    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Лог клиента

```
open
{"id":5,"name":"Ivan","text":"Hello"}
on Failure null
```

Comment: В коде не видно чтобы вы сообщение обратно слали. Также, наверное, будет полезно больше информации в onFailure вывести. Например printStackTrace у ошибки вызвать и вывести в логи response

Comment: Ошибка в логах выскакивает если на сервер какое-то время нет запросов